# Apache Flink - process pojo messages from Kinesis with EventTimeSessionWindows

Tags: session, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to use EventTimeSessionWindows when consuming json messages from AWS Kinesis.
What I have so far:

```
DataStream<SamplePojo> kinesis = env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(
            "my-stream",
            new POJODeserializationSchema(),
            kinesisConsumerConfig));


DataStream<SamplePojo> aggregated = kinesis
            .keyBy("someProperty1")
            .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(2L)))
            .sum("indicator");


//kinesis.print();
aggregated.print();
env.execute();
```

where POJODeserializationSchema is like in [Apache Flink - how to send and consume POJOs using AWS Kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885446/apache-flink-how-to-send-and-consume-pojos-using-aws-kinesis)

This relies on the basic example from documentation which receives Tuple3:

```
DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> aggregated = source
        .keyBy(0)
        .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.milliseconds(3L)))
        .sum(2);
```

but `aggregated` seems to be empty.. any ideas?
(`kinesis.print()` does show all the messages thrown into kinesis)

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide timestamp and watermarks for your stream like in [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#timestamp-assigners--watermark-generators).

Something like:

```
DataStream<Tuple3<String, Long, Integer>> aggregated = source
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AscendingTimestampExtractor<SamplePojo>() {...})
    .keyBy(0)
    .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.milliseconds(3L)))
    .sum(2);
```

Also note you have to enable `TimeCharacterist.EventTime`:

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

Comment: Actually what I really want is my application to output objects which represent the entire session (SamplePojo = Event)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with:

```
 DataStream<SamplePojo> aggregated = kinesis.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks((new AscendingTimestampExtractor<SamplePojo>() {
                @Override
                public long extractAscendingTimestamp(SamplePojo samplePojo) {
                    return samplePojo.getSomeProperty2();
                }
            }));

 aggregated
       .keyBy((event) -> event.getSomeProperty1())
       .timeWindow(Time.seconds(1));

 aggregated.print();
```

Thanks Dawid Wysakowicz for the useful link