# Apache Flink - how to send and consume POJOs using AWS Kinesis

Tags: pojo, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, flink-streaming

I want to consume POJOs arriving from Kinesis with Flink.
Is there any standard for how to correctly send and deserialize the messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it with:

```
DataStream<SamplePojo> kinesis = see.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(
        "my-stream",
        new POJODeserializationSchema(),
        kinesisConsumerConfig));
```

and

```
public class POJODeserializationSchema extends AbstractDeserializationSchema<SamplePojo> {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public SamplePojo deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        if (mapper == null) {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        }

        SamplePojo retVal = mapper.readValue(message, SamplePojo.class);

        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(SamplePojo nextElement) {
        return false;
    }
}
```